# electron exe dont run npm start

Tags: angular, electron

i have built an electron / angular application that works. if i run "npm start" via code editior and then open the exe my app works. is there a way to include this command in my application so that when i run the exe it also runs automatically?

Things i tryed that dont worked:

in main.ts:

`import {exec} from 'child_process'`

`const child = exec('npm start');`

in electron.dev.js:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')

const child= exec('npm start')
```